# Como deixar cada categoria de uma cor no wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Estou tentando colorir o background do link de cada categoria, deixando cada um de uma cor, mas queria que estilizasse APENAS os links da categorias na página inicial, não quero alterar o style na pagina das categorias. É algo assim que estou tentando fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber se é possível fazer isso e se poderiam me ajuda.
Esse é o meu código até agora:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="artigo">
<div class="post-header"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); ?></div> 

<div class="icons-categ"><?php the_category('') ?></div>
</div>



<?php endwhile?>    <?php else: ?>    <?php endif; ?>   

</div>
```

Esse é o código das categorias que tenho no css, mas ele parece que não funciona:

```
.category-noticias .icons-categ {
    background: #e07737;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-celebridades .icons-categ {
    background: #1865e4;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-musicas .icons-categ {
    background: #aa0909;
    color:#fff;
}

.category-filmes .icons-categ {
    background: #b6e037;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Obs: estou utilizando o wordpress e bootstrap

Comment: Não sei se vai dar certo, mas vc pode tentar no CSS usar nth-child, tipo assim `[class*="category-"]:nth-child(1) .icons-categ {
    background: #e07737 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}` e depois vc vai fazendo `:nth-child(2)`, `:nth-child(3)` para cada categoria que vc tenha, pode ser que funcione...

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a função `get_the_category()` no lugar da `the_category()`. Só existe um porém e não sei se você pensou nisso, mas e se um post pertencer a duas ou mais categorias? Qual a cor que você vai utilizar?
Estou perguntando isso porque a função `get_the_category()` vai retornar todas as categorias do `post` então como você não mencionou essa possibilidade, a minha solução para resolver isso será utilizar a cor da primeira categoria do `post`, não é a melhor solução mas acredito que ajude bastante.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="artigo">
            <div class="post-header"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large'); ?></div> 
            <?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
            <?php $category = (count($categories) > 0 ? $categories[0] : null); ? // Caso tenha categoria eu pego a primeira>
            <?php if (null !== $category): // Só vamos exibir essa parte se tiver categoria ?>
                <!-- Vamos criar a classe de cada elemento dinamicamente utilizando o slug da categoria -->
                <div class="icons-categ category-<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile?>    
    <?php else: ?>    
        <!-- Mensagem de que não existe posts ou algo do tipo -->
    <?php endif; ?>   
</div>
```

```
.icons-categ {
    color:#fff;
}

.category-noticias {
    background: #e07737;
}

.category-celebridades {
    background: #1865e4;
}

.category-musicas {
    background: #aa0909;
}

.category-filmes {
    background: #b6e037;
}
```